# Subscribe to Youtube Channel using Google authentication (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, google-api

Good afternoon

I use your this examples: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services  for authorization to Google and getting a token for subscription to the Youtube channel.
To do this, use the following function:

```
-(void) subscription{

    NSString *channelId = @«MyChannelId»;
    NSString *api_Key = @«MY_IOS_API_KEY»;

    AFHTTPRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&key=%@", api_Key];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.authentication.accessToken];
    NSLog(@"Access Token: %@", [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.authentication.accessToken);

    [requestSerializer setValue: authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"snippet":@{
                                     @"resourceId":@{
                                             @"channelId":channelId,
                                             @"kind":@"youtube#channel"
                                             }
                                     }
                             };
    [manager POST:URLString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@«OK:»);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@«Faild:»);
    }];
}
```

And then transmits the values obtained in:

```
- (void) receiveToggleAuthUINotification:(NSNotification *) notification {

    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"ToggleAuthUINotification"]) {
        [self subscriptionBtn];   
    }
}
```

I got the following error from the failure block:

```
error =     {
    code = 403;
    errors =         (
                    {
            domain = usageLimits;
            extendedHelp = "https://console.developers.google.com";
            message = "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.";
            reason = ipRefererBlocked;
        }
    );
    message = "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.";
};
```

Comment: Just a guess here.  But in google developer console you created an API key for iOS when you did you added something like com.example.myapp it needs to match the app you are sending it from.

Comment: Hi, DaImTo. My bundle ID app and ID from google developer console is already match